# Is there any difference between a huge full site css file structure and seperated css files for different pages?

Tags: html, css

Something like
-main.css
That contains all the css for the website.

vs

-home.css, product.css, content.css
For different pages.

Is there anything to worry about in any of the structures??

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Ethan Honestly I don't need anything. I'm Just curious about how it works. And if there's any fundamental rule? Just suppose you have website that has 10 to 15 pages. Now if you create a huge main.css file. And link em to all the pages. Like one file linked to all. Is that "bad"? oor good? And on the other hand if i create single css file for every page. Or maybe like css file for portion of my pages. Is that "bad"?? Or good?? I hope it helps you understand what im saying. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Of course. Imagine loading this huge main.css file on every single page of your website, it would be the optimalization nightmare. That's why we have many different ways to split our css files to smaller and faster solutions.

Comment: "Imagine loading this huge main.css file on every single page of your website" — That would be pretty awful. Happily, we have caching.

Comment: Wait what? Are we talking about single file for single page or single file for whole webapp? If first one, I agree it's better to load (most of the times) a single file for a single page, but if you want to cache huge css file that could weight a ton, then I don't think it's the best idea lol. Educate me if I'm wrong.